# Excel web acces to update thorugh more then 1 sheet

Tags: web-part

I have a Excel chart insertet.

The problem is that, the data it gets, it gets through a "middle man" sheet.

15->1->webpart updates from that 1 sheet.

15 people are using the sheets - and the 1 collects data, the problem is the "1" is never open, so it doesnt refresh the chart. Is there any way to work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are a variety of ways automate the data refresh -- either updating the consolidation workbook (Excel services, macro or code); replacing the workbook as the data store (Access, DBMS); or thoguh use of an ETL tool. All would depend on your enviroment and requirments, Depending on your enviroment and requirments.

Link to a nicely indepth post on how to use Excel services:
http://tavislovell.com/the-dark-art-of-the-excel-services-workbook-data-refresh/